# How alter column type with using toUInt32OrZero function in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I have String column in clickhouse table.
I try alter table with modify type to UInt32:

```
ALTER TABLE main.abonents
MODIFY COLUMN 
device_type UInt32 DEFAULT 0
```

but have error:

```
 
Received exception from server:
Code: 6. DB::Exception: Received from 5.200.55.122:9000. DB::Exception: Cannot parse string 'mo' as UInt32: syntax error at begin of string. Note: there are toUInt32OrZero function, which returns zero instead of throwing exception..
```

It's clear, clickhouse use `toUint32` function on string like 'mobile' and throw exception. And its advice to use function `toUInt32OrZero` to convert type.

How can i use `toUInt32OrZero` function with ALTER TABLE??

Answer (score 1):

There's no such way (as far as I know).

You can achieve it with a second table. Let's create one:

```
CREATE TABLE main.abonents_new AS main.abonents;
```

Then we have to alter column in that new table. 
This table has no data yet, so it won't raise exceptions:

```
ALTER TABLE main.abonents_new MODIFY COLUMN device_type UInt32 DEFAULT 0;
```

Then, make sure no new data is written to main.abonents. We'd like to keep everything in place when we'll transfer the data to the new table.

Insert the data using INSERT INTO SELECT query. Make sure to list all the fields with the same order; wrap device_type to the converter function (`toUInt32OrZero`) :

```
INSERT INTO main.abonents_new SELECT field1, field2, ..., toUInt32OrZero(device_type) AS device_type, ..., fieldN FROM main.abonents;
```

Then, make sure that everything's alright (that rows count is the same, device_type was converted as intended, etc), then rename the tables:

```
RENAME TABLE main.abonents TO main.abonents_old;
RENAME TABLE main.abonents_new TO main.abonents;
```

(or, you may `DROP` the older table instead; although I'd keep the old data to be able to restore if things'd go south)